# Laravel send query string with optional parameters

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.6

I have my route set as

```
Route::any('/{brand?}/{type?}/{city?}', 'SearchController@index')->name('search');
```

I want to send from my controller query strings (Form GET params)

After searching I ended up with this but it does not work properly

```
return redirect()->route('search', [$brand->name, $type->name, 'search_model_from' => $request->search_model_from, 'search_model_to' => $request->search_model_to]);
```

which returns back

localhost:8000/toyota/avalon/2018?search_model_to=2019

I want to return

localhost:8000/toyota/avalon/?search_model_from=2018&search_model_to=2019

What I am trying to achieve in general is SEO friendly search functionality

Comment: can you add your `SearchController@index ` method here  ?

Comment: Maybe you should try to assign city as null like that : 
`return redirect()->route('search', ['brand' => $brand->name, 'type' => $type->name, 'city' => '',  'search_model_from' => $request->search_model_from, 'search_model_to' => $request->search_model_to]);`

Comment: @JulienMetral Yep, that solved it :)
Add it as an answer so I could mark as solved..And Thank you, good sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try to assign city as null like that :

```
return redirect()->route('search', [
    'brand' => $brand->name, 'type' => $type->name, 
    'city' => '', 'search_model_from' => $request->search_model_from, 
    'search_model_to' => $request->search_model_to
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this could happen because you have defined 3 optional parameters in the route and as you are sending just two of them, this might takes the next (in this case 'search_model_from') as the third parameter for url.

Maybe if you cast and set a default value to the optional parameters in your Controller, you won't have that trouble, like this:

```
public function index(string $brand='', string $type='', string $city='' , $other_parameters)
```